# cakePHP Ajax view

Tags: ajax, cakephp

When setting `$this->layout = 'ajax'` cake still expects the view file for that action.

My question is, do I still need to create that view file, or is there a way to circumvent that. I don't wish to have ajax actions with one-liner view files such as `'<?php echo $data; ?>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your ajax method. Then you don't need page for your ajax method

```
public function action_name() {
   $this->layout = 'ajax';
   ...
   ...
   $this->autoRender = false;
   echo $data;
}
```

Comment: $this->Layout !== $this-layout !

Comment: the above answer works ! Thanks! @mark, what is wrong with the answer? Or what you suggested is just another way of doing it ?

Comment: It implies that $this->Layout is wrong and the documented $this->layout should be used instead. And that one should mind the casing. I took the liberty of correcting the answer.